# Filtering a Spring XML file from a dependent project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a project MyProject which has a dependency on configuration in another project, BaseProject. Inside BaseProject I have dependencies to many different projects like ErrorLogging, PerformanceLogging, etc... I want to be able to build the top level project (MyProject) and have it filter all the spring xml files in those projects that it has as dependencies. I'm not having any luck. I can see the beans but they are not being filtered. Some of the beans are being filtered with default filters defined in their own poms but non are using the filters from MyProject.

MyProject - This contains the filter files and imports the config from the other projects.

BaseProject - Has spring beans defined which require filtering.

ErrorLogging - Has spring beans defined which require filtering.

When I run a package from MyProject all the spring files are correctly extracted into the jar file but they still contain the property placeholder values ${error.logging.host} for example... The beans in MyProject are correctly filtered. The alternative to this is to define the beans in MyProject but there are about 10 of these projects which use BaseProject and it's beans and I do not want to have to redefine them across 10 seperate projects.

If anyone could shed any light on this issue it'd be great. Thanks

Edit :

To make this clearer, I have a spring beans xml definition inside of the project ErrorLogging called errors-config.xml which defines beans for connecting to databases. This just has place holders for the connection details which should be provided by the filter.properties file that is inside of MyProject.

errors-config.xml is imported as a resource into baseproject-config.xml which sits inside of the BaseProject. Base project and it's config file are imported to MyProject.

I then build MyProject using Maven and I would like the property placeholders inside of errors-config.xml to be replaced with the values in the filter.properties in MyProject. MyProject can successfully filter it's own files but not those of ErrorsLogging project. ErrorsLogging seems to pick up filters from it's own src/main/resources folder instead of that of MyProject.

Comment: Could you please provide more details. That is an example of beans defined in the BaseProject or the ErrorLogging project and how you tried to exclude them in the MyProject context.

Comment: I'll edit the post since it's easier

Comment: Seems like a job for `PropertiesPlaceHolderConfigurer` see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context-pphc

Comment: Well I think that I need something more specific since I'm defining the properties files already. I think it must be something to do with the order that occurs when filtering, loading the spring context files and extracting them into the target folder from the dependencies. I recon they are filtered first then they are extracted as I get filter values coming from the default filter for ErrorLogging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by unpacking all the dependencies, filtering and packing again, the whole process depends on the structure of your project, for a basic configuration this may suffices:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
            <!--unpack all the dependencies to the target of this project-->        
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>${pom.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}</outputDirectory>
                <includes>**/*.properties,**/*.xml</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>${config.maven.plattform.resources}/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>zip</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <goals>
                <goal>assembly</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This should work as long as you have correctly defined the correct filtering of the resources (which takes places later and also uses the maven-resources-plugin).

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply, I'll look into this at one point shortly when I get some time. This looks more like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` to override the initial properties.
For example, if you have the folowing datasource definition in `errors-config.xml` :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${hibernate.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${hibernate.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${hibernate.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.password}" />
</bean>
```

You can override the database connection properties in the `MyProject` context like this :

```
<bean id="propertyOverideConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>filter.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And in the `filter.properties` file you need to specify the bean names and properties you wish to override :

```
datasource.driverClass = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
datasource.jdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
datasource.user = username
datasource.password = password
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DeliveryNinja Was this helpful?

Comment: I can't reply here it's too long lol. In a nut shell this didn't work. This is just specifying a filter.properties file to use but this filtering occures before the beans are imported to MyProject from ErrorLogging/BaseProject so errors-config.xml just uses it's own filter.properties ( defined in it's pom.xml) and not the filter.properites of MyProject.